# How to split array into symbol?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I need to create a hash with static data and data returned from a query and don't wanna to call pluck twice.

Ex:

```
network = {type: "manager", name: Profile.where(id: x.user_id).pluck(:name), email: Profile.where(id: x.user_id).pluck(:email) }
```

The line above works but i Trying to do that with only one call like:

```
network = {type: "manager", (name:, email:) : Profile.where(id: x.user_id).pluck(:name, :email).flatten } # don't work
```

Desired output:

```
profile #=> {:type=>"manager", :name=>"Ruby", :email =>"ruby@blahblahblah.com"}
```

Any idea?

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking about. Also, why do you need that, exactly?

Comment: what if it looks like `profile = {[:name, :age, :gender] : ["Ruby", 21, "female"]}`

Comment: It is not a valid object. It would cause a parsing error. You cannot do anything within Ruby.

Comment: Consider using [Structs](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Struct.html) instead to make it easier for you.

Comment: Sergio please read the question again ;)

Comment: I have updated my answer according to your update

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now I understand your question.

You can do

```
network = { type: "manager" }
network.merge Hash[[:name, :email].zip Profile.where(id: x.user_id).pluck(:name, :email).flatten]
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply save the profile with both the name and the email into a variable:

```
profile = Profile.select(:name, :email).where(id: x.user_id).first
```

then add the values into your hash:

```
network = {type: "manager", name: profile.name, email: profile.email }
```